# Sending Requests to Https site

Tags: go, https, get

Essentially, through goLang I'm trying to send a request on a https site to check if an item is on the site.
I have tried to attempt a request to the main site, but keep getting access denied and need a way to tackle this, I'm trying to get the info from the body to separate it and find the correct ids to check if something is on the site.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

   url := "https://www.jdsports.co.uk/"

   req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

   res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

   defer res.Body.Close()

   body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

   fmt.Println(string(body)) 
}
```

Comment: I am getting access denied, server not allowed to send requet

Comment: @ThunderCat please try on new url you will see

Comment: Other than the ignored errors, the application correctly requests a resource from the server.  Perhaps the service provider can provide assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing a little bit, it looks like that specific website is using Akamai Ghost and has been configured to block the default go http package user agent.

The default user agent appears to be `Go-http-client/1.1`

If you change your user agent

```
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "my-client-app")
```

The request will work. However, the website in question appears to not want to be programatically crawled. Perhaps you should respect their wishes.